# How can I get a hold of Sencha GRUI?

Tags: reactjs, sencha-grui, grui

I saw some webinar from Sencha, and I am planning to use GRUI from Sencha in my next React project, Is it available over NPM? full feature? Where to find and download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: Evaluation copy is available via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sencha/sencha-grid), but you have to [buy the full version](https://sencha-grid-storybook-test.csi-infra.com/?path=/story/docs-enterprise-information--page). It is not available via download as other ExtJS products.

Please follow the following link to the documentation:

[GRUI documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/sencha_grui/index.html)

Details on GRUI can be accessed easily by visiting the [Sencha GRUI page](https://www.sencha.com/products/grui/).
It is available over NPM and can be consumed like any other package.
For evaluation, all the features are available and can be checked over a development environment; but [some advanced features](https://sencha-grid-storybook-test.csi-infra.com/?path=/story/docs-enterprise-information--page) will require license activation to be enabled in a production environment.
You can the NPM package from our [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sencha/sencha-grid).